# Oracle SQL MIN and MAX combination from same table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have below mentioned data. I am looking to get max of Start message and corresponding min or success message.

Start Message Table

```
ID1     Timestamp_start_msg_recieved    date        jobid      message time in seconds
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29              5/14/2014   abc        start 262
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31              5/14/2014   abc        start 264
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:45              5/14/2014   abc        start 278
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:50              5/14/2014   abc        start 285
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:04              5/14/2014   abc        start 165
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06              5/14/2014   abc        start 2167
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:16              5/14/2014   abc        start 2180
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:26              5/14/2014   abc        start 2190
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11              5/14/2014   abc        start 8767
1234    5/14/2014 16:48:20              5/14/2014   abc        start 878
1234    5/14/2014 19:02:52              5/14/2014   abc        start 687
5678    5/14/2014 22:02:52              5/14/2014   pqr        start 501
5678    5/14/2014 23:10:40              5/14/2014   pqr        start 200
```

Success Message Table

```
ID1     Timestamp_success_msg_recieved  date        jobid  message time in seconds
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:52              5/14/2014   abc    successful 290
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:32              5/14/2014   abc    successful 4280 
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:15              5/14/2014   abc    successful 8774
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:18              5/14/2014   abc    successful 8777
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:19              5/14/2014   abc    successful 8778
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:25              5/14/2014   abc    successful 8784
1234    5/14/2014 16:48:22              5/14/2014   abc    successful 880 
1234    5/14/2014 19:03:00              5/14/2014   abc    successful 699
5678    5/14/2014 22:03:00              5/14/2014   pqr    successful 250
5678    5/19/2014 14:00:16              5/19/2014   pqr    successful 400
```

#### Expected Result

```
ID1  IMESTAMP_for_start_message TIMESTAMP_for_success_message    Date       Jobid    msg  msg start_secs success_secs
1234 5/14/2014 10:02:50         5/14/2014 10:02:52           5/14/2014  abc start success 262 290 
1234 5/14/2014 10:09:26         5/14/2014 10:09:32           5/14/2014  abc start success 2190 4280
1234 5/14/2014 11:45:11         5/14/2014 11:45:25           5/14/2014  abc start success 8767 8784
1234 5/14/2014 16:48:20         5/14/2014 16:48:22           5/14/2014  abc start success 878 880
1234 5/14/2014 19:02:52         5/14/2014 19:03:00           5/14/2014  abc start success 687 699
5678 5/14/2014 22:02:52         5/14/2014 22:03:00           5/14/2014  pqr start success 501 699
5678 5/14/2014 23:10:40         null                         5/14/2014  pqr start success 250 null
5678    null                   5/19/2014 14:00:16            5/19/2014  pqr null  success null 400
```

I am looking for Max of start message and start_secs to pair up with min of success message and success_secs. Tried using Temporary table using WITH clause and also used self join method. Below is my query, But WITH clause query returns MIN of overall data in the table.

Query Used:

```
WITH DATA AS
  (SELECT MIN(smt.column13) timestamp_for_success_message
  FROM success_table1 smt, start_table2 b
     WHERE
    (SMT.id1 = b.id1)
    AND (SMT.jobid = b.jobid)
    AND (SMT.timestamp_for_success_message_recieved >= b.timestamp_for_start_message_recieved)
  )
SELECT distinct a.timestamp_for_success_message_recieved,
  b.timestamp_for_start_message_recieved,
  b.id1,
  b.jobid
FROM data a,
  start_table2 b
order by b.timestamp_start_message_recieved, a.timestamp_for_success_message_recieved, b.jobid, b.id1;
```

Comment: Clearly neither `ID1` nor `Jobid` (nor the pair) is a unique key for either table.  In fact, neither table appears to have any candidate key narrower than a whole row, unless possibly the timestamps could serve.  Do `ID1` values and `Jobid` values always have a 1:1 relationship, as in the example?

Comment: You need to explain in more details how you got to that results set. As it is stands right now I don't know if there is a way to answer this.

Comment: based on expected output,you always get the max date in both cases, grouped by minutes. am i wrong?

Comment: I answered below, but it appears your expected result is actually the max start and the max success. Your start at 11:45:11 should pair with the success at 11:45:15, but you have it paired with the success at 11:45:25.

Comment: @BenGrimm: Yes, It is a typo. I will correct it now. Start at 11:45:11 should pair with Success at 11:45:11.

Comment: And can the actual messages be assumed constant, as in the example, or do they need to actually be selected from their respective tables?

Comment: @Aramillo: Based on the current query I get min of all the dataset for Success paired up with all of the start messages.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes, the messages are constant. They just need to be pulled in as any other column

Comment: No, if they are constant then they don't need to be read from the tables at all.  They can just be selected as constants.  That is, in fact, the whole point of the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: yes, you are right. We can leave them out too. I am trying to understand how does message itself would help change the query and make it efficient?

Comment: How are you able to have column names like `timestamp_for_success_message_recieved` in Oracle? That is 38 characters long.

Comment: @DavidFaber: I have renamed these columns for convenience of understanding. They are something else in actual dataset.

Comment: Are start_secs=262 and start_secs=250 really correct in the first and last row respectively of the expected result?

Comment: @Abecee: Each id and jobid has its own secs. So the key here is to pair max of start_timestamp and time_in_secs_for_start_msg with min of succes(timestamp and time in secs)

Comment: Could you, please, make this more explicit? (i) In your expected result, you have five records where "id1" = "1234" AND "jobID" = "abc". (ii) Does that combining timestamp and "time in secs" (you are talking about now) suggest, there are even more records in the actual data with "id1" = "1234" AND "jobID" = "abc"? (iii) Could you run the query in my below answer against actual data, and update the sample data to demonstrate, where it fails?

Comment: (iv) Could you increase the amount of actual data queried starting from, e.g., the equivalent for (half) an hour to identify the point, where the query seems not to return? (v) How does creating indices affect query performance? (vi) Are you allowed to issue `ALTER TABLE` statements? (Or could get somebody to do it on your behalf?)

Comment: (vii) Some of the timestamps and seconds don't seem to align within the tables (take start 2014-05-14 10:09:04 - 165 = 2014-05-14 10:06:19 and 2014-05-14 10:09:06 - 2167 = 2014-05-14 09:32:59) and even less across tables (compare start examples to  2014-05-14 10:09:32 - 4280 = 2014-05-14 08:58:12). What am I missing here?

Comment: @Abecee: Seconds really are a time measurement from a constant time decided as reference timezone. The seconds mentioned int he question is just reference. It would not match based on date and timestamp mentioned.

Comment: Well… Did you have a chance to run below suggestions against the real data? In particular the `LEAD` using one?

Comment: @Abecee: The one with LEAD works perfectly with having to do a little post processing. Since LEAD command shows the very next entry in message(start or success), result of Detail temp table works accurately when LEAD calculation for Time_in_secs is removed as it gives multiple results. It worked fine when I added one more temp table with LEAD function showing Time_in_secs. Could not make the second query work though. It gives multiple combinatios of results when run on original data.

Comment: @Abecee: I am inspired by your dedication to problem solving. It makes me explore more options of a single solution.

Comment: Glad to hear, you seem to have found, what you were looking for. The second query is based on assumptions (derived from the sample data), which turned out to be wrong. On the other hand, if for the actual data the timestamps and seconds combined do actually reference points in time exactly, one could work from there. The query in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f1a2d/4) should return a set, where "message" alternates between "start" and "successful" for respectively identical "id1" and "jobID".

Comment: If so, these subqueries could be `JOIN`ed instead of `UNION`ed. (It's not working for the sample data - which is in line with you saying, timestamps and seconds not to be consistent.) But this is likely to be computational more complex, and thus more resource consuming. Not sure, whether "LEAD calculation for Time_in_secs […] gives multiple results" is hinting at data inconsistencies.

Comment: @Abecee: Could you help me with a way to find null values if no start message is present?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data to test against? Preferably with consistent "timestamp" and "time_in_seconds" data. What's the purpose of the check? Do you want to create fake start records? Do you want the respective success messages to be listed despite no start message being available? Please provide more detail.

Comment: You might want to add a new section to your request (in order to keep existing answer relevant) - or even to create a completely new request…

Comment: @Abecee: Sounds good. I will go ahead and create a completely new request. I have edited the question and expected result though. I have scenarios where there would be success message but not start message before that, In such cases I would like to catch the start_timestamp as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sample data, the following works as well

```
WITH
RawData AS (
  SELECT
    id1
    , jobID
    , message
    , TIMESTAMP_for_start_message timeStamp
    , time_in_seconds
  FROM StartMessageTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    id1
    , jobID
    , message
    , TIMESTAMP_success_msg_received
    , time_in_seconds
  FROM SuccessMessageTable
  ORDER BY id1, jobID, 4
),
Detail AS (
  SELECT
    id1
    , jobID
    , message message1
    , LEAD (message, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id1, jobID, timeStamp) message2
    , timeStamp timeStamp1
    , LEAD (timeStamp, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id1, jobID, timeStamp) timeStamp2
    , time_in_seconds secs1
    , LEAD (time_in_seconds, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id1, jobID, timeStamp) secs2
  FROM RawData
)
SELECT
  id1
  , timeStamp1 TIMESTAMP_for_start_message
  , timeStamp2 TIMESTAMP_for_success_message
  , jobID
  , 'start' msgStart
  , 'success' msgSuccess
  , secs1 start_secs
  , secs2 success_secs
FROM Detail
WHERE (message1 = 'start' AND message2 = 'successful') OR message2 IS NULL
ORDER BY timeStamp1
;
```

with the same caveat regarding the first and last value in the "start_secs" column.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f1a2d/1)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: According to OP's feedback, the query fails for the live data. This is likely due to
`GROUP BY (TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_for_start_message, 'MI'))`
not correctly grouping the records for "id1" and "jobID".

---

For the sample data the following works

```
WITH
LatestStart AS (
  SELECT
    MAX(TIMESTAMP_for_start_message) TIMESTAMP_for_start_message
  FROM StartMessageTable
  GROUP BY (TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_for_start_message, 'MI'))
),
LatestStartEarliestSuccess AS (
  SELECT
    LS.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message
    , (SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMP_success_msg_received)
       FROM SuccessMessageTable
       WHERE
         (id1 = StMT.id1)
         AND (someDate = StMT.someDate)
         AND (jobID = StMT.jobID)
         AND (TIMESTAMP_success_msg_received >= StMT.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message)) TIMESTAMP_for_success_message
  FROM LatestStart LS
  JOIN StartMessageTable StMT
    ON LS.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message = StMT.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message
),
Detail AS (
  SELECT
    StMT.id1
    , LSES.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message
    , LSES.TIMESTAMP_for_success_message
    , StMT.jobID
    , 'start' msgStart
    , 'success' msgSuccess
    , StMT.time_in_seconds start_secs
    , SuMT.time_in_seconds success_secs
  FROM LatestStartEarliestSuccess LSES
  JOIN StartMessageTable StMT
    ON LSES.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message = StMT.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message
  LEFT JOIN SuccessMessageTable SuMT
    ON LSES.TIMESTAMP_for_success_message = SuMT.TIMESTAMP_success_msg_received
  ORDER BY LSES.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message
)
SELECT
  * FROM Detail
;
```

except for the first and last value in the "start_secs" column - which, however, seem to deviate from the sample input.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27e860/24)

---

Edit: **IIF** the respective "timestamp" and "second" values do -across tables- correctly reference points in time for combinations of "id1" and "jobID", the following provides an alternative starting point:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  id1
  , jobID
  , message
--  , TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP_for_start_message, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') timestamp
  , TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP_for_start_message - NUMTODSINTERVAL(time_in_seconds, 'SECOND'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') job_start_time
--  , time_in_seconds
FROM StartMessageTable
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
  id1
  , jobID
  , message
--  , TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP_success_msg_received, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') timestamp
  , TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP_success_msg_received - NUMTODSINTERVAL(time_in_seconds, 'SECOND'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') job_start_time
--  , time_in_seconds
FROM SuccessMessageTable
ORDER BY id1, jobID, 4, message;
```

However, with the `LEAD` approach (given in another answer to this question) returning the wanted, it's probably not worth to look further into that option.