# SQL MIN values from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have below mentioned data. I am looking to get min of Start message and corresponding min of success message. If there is no start or success message present then it should show null.

Start Message Table

```
ID1     Timestamp_start_msg_recieved    date        jobid      message time in seconds
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29              5/14/2014   abc        start 262
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31              5/14/2014   abc        start 264
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:45              5/14/2014   abc        start 278
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:50              5/14/2014   abc        start 285
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:04              5/14/2014   abc        start 165
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:06              5/14/2014   abc        start 2167
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:16              5/14/2014   abc        start 2180
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:26              5/14/2014   abc        start 2190
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:11              5/14/2014   abc        start 8767
1234    5/14/2014 16:48:20              5/14/2014   abc        start 878
1234    5/14/2014 19:02:52              5/14/2014   abc        start 687
5678    5/14/2014 22:02:52              5/14/2014   pqr        start 501
5678    5/14/2014 23:10:40              5/14/2014   abcd        start 200
```

Success Message Table

```
ID1     Timestamp_success_msg_recieved  date        jobid  message time in seconds
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:52              5/14/2014   abc    successful 290
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:32              5/14/2014   abc    successful 4280 
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:15              5/14/2014   abc    successful 8774
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:18              5/14/2014   abc    successful 8777
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:19              5/14/2014   abc    successful 8778
1234    5/14/2014 11:45:25              5/14/2014   abc    successful 8784
1234    5/14/2014 16:48:22              5/14/2014   abc    successful 880 
1234    5/14/2014 19:03:00              5/14/2014   abc    successful 699
5678    5/14/2014 22:03:00              5/14/2014   pqr    successful 250
5678    5/19/2014 14:00:16              5/19/2014   pqr    successful 400
```

#### Expected Result

```
ID1  IMESTAMP_for_start_message TIMESTAMP_for_success_message    Date       Jobid    msg  msg start_secs success_secs
1234 5/14/2014 10:02:29         5/14/2014 10:02:52           5/14/2014  abc start success 262 290 
1234 5/14/2014 10:09:04         5/14/2014 10:09:32           5/14/2014  abc start success 165 4280
1234 5/14/2014 11:45:11         5/14/2014 11:45:25           5/14/2014  abc start success 8767 8784
1234 5/14/2014 16:48:20         5/14/2014 16:48:22           5/14/2014  abc start success 878 880
1234 5/14/2014 19:02:52         5/14/2014 19:03:00           5/14/2014  abc start success 687 699
5678 5/14/2014 22:02:52         5/14/2014 22:03:00           5/14/2014  pqr start success 501 699
5678 5/14/2014 23:10:40         null                         5/14/2014  abcd start success 250 null
5678    null                   5/19/2014 14:00:16            5/19/2014  pqr null  success null 400
```

I am trying to get Min of start_timestamp in combination with the very next Min of success_timestamp corresponding to id1 and jobid. If there is a list of start message and no success message for a given id1 and jobid, then it should show NULL and viceversa. Tried using Temporary table using WITH clause and also used self join method. Below is my query, But WITH clause query returns MIN of overall data in the table.

Query Used:

```
WITH DATA AS
  (SELECT MIN(smt.column13) timestamp_for_success_message
  FROM success_table1 smt, start_table2 b
     WHERE
    (SMT.id1 = b.id1)
    AND (SMT.jobid = b.jobid)
    AND (SMT.timestamp_for_success_message_recieved >= b.timestamp_for_start_message_recieved)
  )
SELECT distinct a.timestamp_for_success_message_recieved,
  b.timestamp_for_start_message_recieved,
  b.id1,
  b.jobid
FROM data a,
  start_table2 b
order by b.timestamp_start_message_recieved, a.timestamp_for_success_message_recieved, b.jobid, b.id1;
```

Comment: I don't understand how you're linking your Start Message table with your Success Message table?  By ID1, obviously, however, you're are then (somehow) linking 10:02:29 record with 10:02:52 ? Why ? if you use just jobid, it'l still pick up too many. You need to explain your business logic for the rules to join them .. and explain why the 5678 ones split - because they are "too far apart" ? (ie how far is "too far")

Comment: I am splitting data based on id1 and jobid. Based on each id1 and jobid I need to find min of start messages, till a success message is hit and vice versa. There would be multiple start message and/or success message for a give id1 and jobid.

Comment: ok .. so why do you want to see record "5678", with start time "23:10:40" when no matchin end date could be found, but you don't want to see record "1234" with start time "10:02:31" when other end times got gobbled up ?

Comment: Ohh, I see now what you are saying, I have edited the question now. It would be for a different jobid which is showing null now. I am looking for a combination of start and success message after sorting in ascending order and matching based on id1 and jobid. and if there are multiple start messages for a single success message or vice versa, I want to grab MIN(start msg) and MIN(success msg) combination. If for any reason on that there is not an entry to start or success msg I would want to record it as null

Comment: Readers answering this question, or planning to, should note it was [asked again several hours later here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444842/sql-min-values-from-two-columns-across-two-tables-against-id).

Comment: @halfer: Thank you for posting the link. I could not get a way to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL MIN and MAX combination from same table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828293/oracle-sql-min-and-max-combination-from-same-table)

Answer (score 1):

Closest I can get is this:  You'll notice my below query is showing some starts without ends .. you don't explain what to do with those.  Also, my query links  different starts and ends from you.  You said

> "Min of start message and start_secs to pair up with min of success
>   message"

Which I did below, and it links: "264 with 4280", not "165 with 4280" as you showed. Since 262 was paired up with 290, that means 264 is now the MIN to be matched with the MIN of success, 4280.
If you can further clarify your requirements, I can tweak the query.

```
  with w_start as (
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:02:29','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 262 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:02:31','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 264 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:02:45','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 278 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:02:50','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 285 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:09:04','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 165 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:09:06','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 2167') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:09:16','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 2180') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:09:26','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 2190') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 11:45:11','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 8767') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 16:48:20','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 878 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 19:02:52','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 687 ') msg from dual union all
           select 5678 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 22:02:52','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'pqr' jobid, rtrim('start 501 ') msg from dual union all
           select 5678 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 23:10:40','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abcd' jobid, rtrim('start 200 ') msg from dual 
           ),
     w_success as (
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:02:52', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 290  ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:09:32', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 4280 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 11:45:15', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 8774 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 11:45:18', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 8777 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 11:45:19', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 8778 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 11:45:25', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 8784 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 16:48:22', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 880  ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 19:03:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 699  ') msg from dual union all
           select 5678 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 22:03:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'pqr' jobid, rtrim('successful 250  ') msg from dual union all
           select 5678 id1, to_date('05/19/2014 14:00:16', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/19/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'pqr' jobid, rtrim('successful 400  ') msg from dual 
           ),
     w_sub1 as (
           select id1, jobid, dt, t_start, msg,
                    row_number() over (partition by id1, jobid
                                      order by t_start ) l1
             from w_start
           ),
     w_sub2 as (
           select id1, jobid, dt, t_end, msg,
                    row_number() over (partition by id1, jobid
                                      order by t_end ) l2
             from w_success
           )
  select nvl(a.id1,b.id1) id1, nvl(a.jobid, b.jobid) jobid, nvl(a.dt, b.dt) dt, 
           t_start, t_end, 
           a.msg, b.msg, l1, l2
    from w_sub1  a
        FULL OUTER JOIN w_sub2  b
           ON a.id1      = b.id1
          and a.jobid    = b.jobid
          and a.dt       = b.dt
          and a.l1       = b.l2
   order by 1, 4, 5, 2
  /

         ID1 JOBI DT                   T_START              T_END                MSG        MSG                     L1         L2
  ---------- ---- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ----------
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 10:02:29 14-may-2014 10:02:52 start 262  successful 290           1          1
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 10:02:31 14-may-2014 10:09:32 start 264  successful 4280          2          2
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 10:02:45 14-may-2014 11:45:15 start 278  successful 8774          3          3
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 10:02:50 14-may-2014 11:45:18 start 285  successful 8777          4          4
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 10:09:04 14-may-2014 11:45:19 start 165  successful 8778          5          5
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 10:09:06 14-may-2014 11:45:25 start 2167 successful 8784          6          6
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 10:09:16 14-may-2014 16:48:22 start 2180 successful 880           7          7
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 10:09:26 14-may-2014 19:03:00 start 2190 successful 699           8          8
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 11:45:11                      start 8767                          9
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 16:48:20                      start 878                          10
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 19:02:52                      start 687                          11
        5678 pqr  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 22:02:52 14-may-2014 22:03:00 start 501  successful 250           1          1
        5678 abcd 14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 23:10:40                      start 200                           1
        5678 pqr  19-may-2014 00:00:00                      19-may-2014 14:00:16            successful 400                      2

  14 rows selected.
```

Comment: MIN(Start_timestamp), and its corresponding start_secs should correspond to MIN(success_timestamp) based on id1 and jobid. each row (i.e. id1, jobid, start_timestamp, start_secs) needs to match up to its corresponding Min(success_timestamp) and the entire row.

Comment: Yes ... and  10:02:29 is MIN of start, so it matches with 10:02:52 on success. Next, 10:02:31 is now the MIN of start, so it matches with the new MIN of success: 10:09:32 ... Again, my results seem to agree with that .. your samples, do not ?

Comment: Once we find a pair where we have a combination of start and success message, we look at new start message. So in this case 10:02:29 is min of start message matching with Min of success message at 10:02:52. Then we do not have to consider 10:02:31 as the start message as that is already been used and considered for determining MIN of start-success combination.

Comment: the start message for "10:02:31" is "264" .. when was it "used" ? we used "262" . not "264" .. "264" has not yet been used.

Comment: If you had both the start and success tables under one then it would be:
ID1     Timestamp_msg_recieved    date        jobid      message time in seconds
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:29              5/14/2014   abc        start 262
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:31              5/14/2014   abc        start 264
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:45              5/14/2014   abc        start 278
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:50              5/14/2014   abc        start 285
1234    5/14/2014 10:02:52              5/14/2014   abc    successful 290
1234    5/14/2014 10:09:04              5/14/2014   abc        start 165

Comment: Since the start_secs are corresponding to start_timestamp and id1 and jobid, when a start_timestamp is used, then so is the start_secs column. We do not need to process the start_secs seperately

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you mean there. It's also very very hard to understand what you're trying to say in comments here - and getting long winded. Please revise your post, with **all** your business rules. If you keep changing details and feeding me a little bit at a time, you're never going to get a solution. ;) More detail in the original post to clarify what's being missed. From everything you've said, I still don't see why my query doesn't match it. (I'm sure it doesn't by your rules, but you need to convey those to me in a meaningful way ;) )

Comment: I understand. I am trying to get Min of start_timestamp in combination with the very next Min of success_timestamp corresponding to id1 and jobid. If there is a list of start message and no success message for a given id1 and jobid, then it should show NULL and viceversa.

Comment: We can ignore start_secs and success_secs for now as I am trying to understand if it would make any difference considering it separately. I will write down same in the question too.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand what you're after, it seems you want to completely ignore the SECONDS component of the listed times? And treat the resulting times as duplicates if they then match (ie 9:21 = 9:31 .. since 9:00 = 9:00 ).

If that's the case, then this query returns your sample (aside from your typo on "11:45:15" showing as "11:45:25" ;)

```
  with w_start as (
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:02:29','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 262 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:02:31','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 264 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:02:45','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 278 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:02:50','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 285 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:09:04','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 165 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:09:06','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 2167') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:09:16','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 2180') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:09:26','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 2190') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 11:45:11','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 8767') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 16:48:20','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 878 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 19:02:52','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('start 687 ') msg from dual union all
           select 5678 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 22:02:52','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'pqr' jobid, rtrim('start 501 ') msg from dual union all
           select 5678 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 23:10:40','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_start, to_date('05/14/2014','mm-dd-yyyy') dt, 'abcd' jobid, rtrim('start 200 ') msg from dual 
           ),
     w_success as (
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:02:52', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 290  ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 10:09:32', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 4280 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 11:45:15', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 8774 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 11:45:18', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 8777 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 11:45:19', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 8778 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 11:45:25', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 8784 ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 16:48:22', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 880  ') msg from dual union all
           select 1234 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 19:03:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'abc' jobid, rtrim('successful 699  ') msg from dual union all
           select 5678 id1, to_date('05/14/2014 22:03:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'pqr' jobid, rtrim('successful 250  ') msg from dual union all
           select 5678 id1, to_date('05/19/2014 14:00:16', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') t_end, to_date('05/19/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 'pqr' jobid, rtrim('successful 400  ') msg from dual 
           ),
     w_sub1 as ( select id1, jobid, dt, t_start, msg, 
                       row_number() over (partition by id1, jobid
                                      order by t_start ) l1
                   from (
                          select id1, jobid, dt, t_start, msg,
                                 row_number() over (partition by id1, jobid, trunc(t_start,'MI')
                                                     order by msg ) r1
                            from w_start
                        )
                  where r1 = 1
           ),
     w_sub2 as ( select id1, jobid, dt, t_end, msg,
                    row_number() over (partition by id1, jobid
                                      order by t_end ) l2
                   from (
                          select id1, jobid, dt, t_end, msg,
                                   row_number() over (partition by id1, jobid, trunc(t_end,'MI')
                                                     order by msg ) r2
                            from w_success
                         )
                  where r2 = 1
           )
  select nvl(a.id1,b.id1) id1, nvl(a.jobid, b.jobid) jobid, nvl(a.dt, b.dt) dt, 
           t_start, t_end, 
           a.msg, b.msg, l1, l2
    from w_sub1  a
        FULL OUTER JOIN w_sub2  b
           ON a.id1      = b.id1
          and a.jobid    = b.jobid
          and a.dt       = b.dt
          and a.t_start  < b.t_end
          and a.l1       = b.l2
   order by 1, 4, 4, 2
  /

         ID1 JOBI DT                   T_START              T_END                MSG        MSG                     L1         L2
  ---------- ---- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ----------
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 10:02:29 14-may-2014 10:02:52 start 262  successful 290           1          1
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 10:09:04 14-may-2014 10:09:32 start 165  successful 4280          2          2
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 11:45:11 14-may-2014 11:45:15 start 8767 successful 8774          3          3
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 16:48:20 14-may-2014 16:48:22 start 878  successful 880           4          4
        1234 abc  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 19:02:52 14-may-2014 19:03:00 start 687  successful 699           5          5
        5678 pqr  14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 22:02:52 14-may-2014 22:03:00 start 501  successful 250           1          1
        5678 abcd 14-may-2014 00:00:00 14-may-2014 23:10:40                      start 200                           1
        5678 pqr  19-may-2014 00:00:00                      19-may-2014 14:00:16            successful 400                      2

  8 rows selected.
```

Comment: Now that I've shown the "complex" way of doing, I'm kinda hoping somebody comes along and posts a 3 liner .. O.o   (I always worry these queries I build are overly complex .. *sigh* )

Comment: Hey, what does the first two temp tables w_start and w_success do here? I have around million records in real data.

Comment: This solution does not work as the ROW NUM condition that is been used is not consistent. We do not know how many multiple start or success messages would be there for a given id1 and jobid

Comment: @Data Analyst: w_start and w_success are just my temp fake copies of your START and SUCCESS tables. I used them to create the fake data we're working with.  What do you mean by "does not work" .. please be more detailed. What do you mean "ROWNUM condition ... is not consistent".  It's very consistent .. and does in fact, produce the output you showed you wanted.  If there is (yet another) side case you failed to describe, *please update your initial post explaining that* - in detail.